# How to display template parameter type name in natvis?

Tags: visual-c++, natvis

I want to extend a natvis visualizer for a (C++) template class. Is there a way to display a type name of the first template parameter?

It would be great for `boost::variant<int,bool> v; v=1;` to display `1 (int)` or something like that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to show `$T1` as a string, wrap it with `"`. For example, for

`<DisplayString>{*($T1*)storage_.data_.buf} {"$T1"}</DisplayString>`

in your case you will see `1 "int"`

Comment: It's also possible to suppress the quotes, like this: {"$T1",sb}.

Comment: I want to achieve it also but failed. Eg: For `Foo<int, 2>` I have used `<DisplayString>{{Foo &lt; {"$T1"}, {$T2} &gt;}}</DisplayString>`. It has printed `Foo <[4], 2>`. I believe here `4` means the `byte` value of the type. I have another type `Foo<std::complex<float>, 2>`, is it possible to display the first parameter type for this class as like as `std::complex<float>, 2>`? I am using `VSCode` in Linux system.

Comment: @user10634362, unfortunately, in your case you have to use MIEngine, which has a lot of limitations. I assume that `<Intrinsic` is also not implemented in MIEngine

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the best solution is to use the standard C++17 `std::variant`. MSVC comes with natvis for this type so that you have a pretty view of the value that is stored.

Here is some natvis code that I just wrote and tested:

```
  <Type Name="boost::variant&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString Condition="which_==0">{*($T1*)storage_.data_.buf}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="which_==1" Optional="true">{*($T2*)storage_.data_.buf}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="which_==2" Optional="true">{*($T3*)storage_.data_.buf}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="which_==3" Optional="true">{*($T4*)storage_.data_.buf}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="which_==4" Optional="true">{*($T5*)storage_.data_.buf}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="which_==5" Optional="true">{*($T6*)storage_.data_.buf}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="which_==6" Optional="true">{*($T7*)storage_.data_.buf}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="which">which_</Item>
      <Item Name="value0" Condition="which_==0">*($T1*)storage_.data_.buf</Item>
      <Item Name="value1" Condition="which_==1" Optional="true">*($T2*)storage_.data_.buf</Item>
      <Item Name="value2" Condition="which_==2" Optional="true">*($T3*)storage_.data_.buf</Item>
      <Item Name="value3" Condition="which_==3" Optional="true">*($T4*)storage_.data_.buf</Item>
      <Item Name="value4" Condition="which_==4" Optional="true">*($T5*)storage_.data_.buf</Item>
      <Item Name="value5" Condition="which_==5" Optional="true">*($T6*)storage_.data_.buf</Item>
      <Item Name="value6" Condition="which_==6" Optional="true">*($T7*)storage_.data_.buf</Item>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
```

It works for any `boost::variant<type_or_types>`.

It has a `DisplayString` that takes the variant's member `storage_` and extracts the buffer `buf`. The address of the buffer is then cast to a pointer to the type that was provided to `std::variant`. As you can see in my code `which_` is zero based, whereas the template parameters are 1 based. I am not interested in the address but in the value, so I am adding a `*` in front of the value.

I also added an `Expand` section so that you can expand a variant. This allows me to show `which_` and to show the value again - this time the column `Type` will show the correct type as you can see in my screen capture (for the variant itself the type is displayed as `boost::variant<…>` and I do not know how to add the type name into the `DisplayString`).

Please note that the `Optional="true"` are required because otherwise we would get a parsing error in cases where less than 7 type parameters are passed (as in `boost::variant<int,bool>`and natvis does not have a `$T7`.

If you need more template parameters, you can easily extend the code.

If you want the `DisplayString` to also shows the index (as an explicit value or coded into the name `value…`), you can easily change it accordingly as in

```
<DisplayString Condition="which_==0">{{which={which_} value0={*($T1*)storage_.data_.buf}}}</DisplayString>
```

Last but not least please note that I did not test very much and that I did not look into `boost::variant` into detail. I saw that `storage_` has members suggesting that there is some alignment in place. So it might not be sufficient to just use `storage_.data_.buf`. It might be necessary to adjust the pointer depending on the alignment being used.

[image: View in Debugger]

Comment: I actually didn't ask for visualizer for variant. I ask for the way to display template class parameter as a string

Comment: @RomanKhvostikov As you can see in my screen capture Visual Studio does display the type (as given as template Parameter). `v` is `boost::variant<int,bool>` and in case the first type is in use, it displays `value0 … <the value> … int`. The `int` in the third column is exactly the type provided as template parameter. If you want to add the type to the first or second column, then I must say that I doubt that this can be achieved.